# Google Cloud App engine error 502

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm new to google cloud platform. I have deployed a dotnet core project to App Engine locate Asian-south-1. But start from yesterday, the server always returns Error code 502 with a message.
"Error: Server Error
The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds."
I also try to create a brand new project and deploy it but still have no lucks. How can I debug to see where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: There seems to be an issue with GAE traffic in Asia, which is probably related to your error. The Google engineering team is investigating it with high priority.

Previous answer in case is it helpful in some way:

To make sure the issue is in your application, I’d start by trying to deploy the sample HelloWorld application as described in the [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/dotnet/quickstart).

If that works you can start debugging your own code. You can check the logs in [Stackdriver](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/logging) and take a look at the App Engine dashboard.
Additionally, you can try [Stackdriver Debugger](https://cloud.google.com/debugger/docs/setup/dotnet) for a closer look at the code, although it is still in alpha, so it may not work perfectly.